# Android Studio Kotlin: How to properly check spaces in a string

Tags: android, string, android-studio, kotlin, spaces

The main thing I'm struggling to check is spaces between characters. I wanted to change a
" " into "_" but only when there is another letter after it... I can't manage to do it. my current check is:

```
for (c in userName) {
    if ("$c" == " ") { //How do I check in here if after c comes another word??
       userName = userName.replace("$c", "_")
     }
    }
```

Comment: you don't need for loop or if loop. this single line will do the work try this :- userName = userName.replace(" ", "_")

Comment: You're correct, thank you, but that still doesn't answer how can I do it only when there is another letter after it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier using the APIs provided in Kotlin

I left some comments to clarify each individual step.
Generally, manual manipulation of strings will be more difficult than the provided APIs

Realistically, usage of RegEx would be your best friend, but I wanted to keep this code related rather than solving it in that manner.

Also, in Kotlin, there is a distinct difference between double quotes `"` and single quotes `'`
Double quotes are a string, and Single quotes are a Char. There is a different API under the 2.

I use the single quote in string iterator methods to keep it more simple and efficient, rather than having to create new strings each time

```
val myUsername = "super dude 25"
val expectedUsername = "super_dude_25"

val lotsOfSpaces = "  super    dude   58    "
val expectedSpaces = "super_dude_58"

fun formatUsername(string: String): String {
    // Set var to detect duplicate chars
    var prevChar = ' '

    return string.trim() // Remove surrounding spaces to simplify
        .replace(' ', '_') // Spaces into underscores
        .filter { char -> // Remove duplicated underscores
            if (char == '_' && prevChar == '_') false
            else {
               prevChar = char
               true 
            }
        }
}

val updated = formatUsername(myUsername)
println(updated) // super_dude_25
assert(updated == expectedUsername)

val second = formatUsername(lotsOfSpaces)
println(second)
assert(second == expectedSpaces)
```

Comment: Incredible solution, Im glad you understood what I meant despite the poor explanation! I implemented the code and it works perfectly, although I think I need to have a deeper look into this solution since it's a lot above my coding level and I must understand it completly. I will mark this as the solution to my question now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
    for (index in userName.indices) {
        val letter = userName[index]
        val nextLetter = userName.getOrNull(index + 1)
        // if nextLetter == null it means end of the userName
        if (nextLetter == null || nextLetter != ' ') {
            // Do the replacement
        }
    }
```